# Get img thumbnails from Vimeo without API

Tags: get, thumbnails, vimeo

Trying to scrape thumbnail from vimeo video player ID, but not getting any response or error code.
I know there is API but this really works like 3month ago now my little app is broken, so what am I doing wrong?

```
Private Function RequestToVimeo(ByVal VimeoVideoID As String, ByVal views As Boolean, rndAgent As Boolean, referer As String, Proxy As WebProxy) As Boolean



ReDownloadJson:

        Dim ResponseString As String = GetJson(VimeoVideoID, Proxy)


       Try
                Thistoken = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of VimeoJson)(ResponseString)
            Catch ex1 As Exception
                Try
                    Thistoken = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of OtherJson.VimeoJson)(ResponseString)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Proxy = Nothing
                    GoTo ReDownloadJson
                End Try
        End Try

        If PreviewBox.ImageLocation Is Nothing OrElse PreviewBox.ImageLocation = String.Empty Then
            PreviewBox.ImageLocation = Thistoken.video.thumbs.base + "_640.jpg"
        End If




            If response IsNot Nothing Then
                response.Close()
            End If
            Return False
        End Try


    End Function
```

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the error you're getting. Without those it is really hard for someone to help you

Comment: thx mate already came up with solution

Answer (score -2):

Ok I fixed somethign and this is correct I hope :)

```
Private Sub getBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles getBtn.Click
    Try
        Dim vimeoUrl As String = "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/"
        Dim vimeoID As String = videoID.Text 'this comes here your vimeo video ID

        If PreviewBox.ImageLocation Is Nothing OrElse PreviewBox.ImageLocation = String.Empty Then
            PreviewBox.ImageLocation = "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/" + vimeoID + "_640.jpg"
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```